# Magento Pending/Approval System For Custom Module Just Like Review Module

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento

I am making a custom module where users can upload design content. I need a approval system for the content just like in case of product reviews. They don’t show on the frontend until approved from admin. I need exactly the same functionality. I tried looking at the review module code but I wasn’t able to figure out how to do this. Looks like it has something to do with:

```
Mage::registry('usePendingFilter');
```

I tried Google but couldn’t find much or anything really. Please help me out with this one.

I appreciate all the help

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you are looking for is in `app/code/core/Mage/Rating`. The `registry` you are referring to is [Magento's Global Variable Registry](http://alanstorm.com/magento_registry_singleton_tutorial). Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I couldn't find the code in Rating. I am using version 1.6.2.0